# "Afterthought" em português

Tags: tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia

[***Afterthought***](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/afterthought) significa em inglês algo que se menciona ou acrescenta mais tarde por não se ter pensado ou planeado dizê-lo antes. Por exemplo:

> "Tens que vir hoje à nossa festa," disse o João. "E traz a tua irmã," acrescentou ele num *afterthought*.
>
> Pergunta o João, "mas tu és médico?" E depois num *afterthought*, "para ires lá dar palpites?"

O [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/afterthought?q=afterthought) diz que o ***afterthought*** é algo que se pensa, diz ou acrescenta mais tarde, sendo frequentemente não cuidadosamente planeado; dá como exemplo:

> Eles convidaram o Jack e a Sarah apenas como um *afterghought*.

O [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/afterthought) dá estes exemplos:

> Então lembrei-me, quase como um *afterthought*, de dar comer ao gato.
>
> O facto estava escondido no meio dum relatório, quase como um *afterthought*.

Como se poderia elegantemente substituir *afterthought* por uma expressão portuguesa nos exemplos acima?

Comment: Não sei se há alguma expressão que possa substituir isso.

Comment: Interessante. Não sabia que em inglês havia um termo que definisse essa pausa na fala. Há algum termo similar em português?

Comment: @felipe Pois, essa é precisamente a minha pergunta. O *afterthought* não é a pausa: é aquilo que se diz depois da pausa. O meu Houaiss inglês-português indica *reflexão posterior, reflexão tardia* e, e esta eu não percebo, *ilação íntima*. Mas não gosto de nenhuma destas.

Comment: @JorgeB. Se não houver, temos que inventar!

Comment: @Jacinto "num reparo"?

Comment: @JorgeB. Não tou a ver bem como é que *reparo* se aplica ali. De alguma forma repara (conserta) o que foi dito antes? No primeiro exemplo podia-se dizer "num já-agora" :)

Comment: Eu usaria: "Tens que vir hoje à nossa festa," disse o João. "E traz a tua irmã," acrescentou ele após refletir.

Answer (score 6):

Ao contrário de "aftertaste" que tem como tradução **"retrogosto"**, termo muito utilizado por enólogos e mestres cervejeiros, não conheço e não encontrei nenhuma palavra em língua portuguesa que signifique exatamente o "afterthought". Acho que se quisermos descrever o pensamento tardio, teremos que usar a "reflexão posterior", "reflexão tardia"; ou então usar apenas "acrescentou".

"Tens que vir hoje à nossa festa," disse o João. "E traz a tua irmã," acrescentou.  (ele numa **"reflexão posterior"**)

Pergunta o João, "mas tu és médico?" E depois numa **"reflexão tardia"**, "para ires lá dar palpites?"

Talvez **"um comentário atrasado"** ou **"um comentário tardio"** servissem, mas não são idiomáticos.

Ocorreu-me também, não tanto como um **afterthought** mas como um **belated thought** a palavra "adendo".  No entanto, após algumas ponderações, achei que é um termo muito literário para aplicarmos à língua falada.

Comment: Parece-me reflexão exagerado. As mais das vezes é só uma ideia que nos ocorre, sem grande reflexão.

Comment: @Jacinto  Concordo, geralmente não há reflexão alguma.  É acrescentado como um reflexo, que no caso nada tem a ver com reflexão.